# Prioritizing execution order of JUNIT test classes

Tags: java, junit

I have two individual test classes ( for example : TestClassA, TestClassB) I want TestClassA to run first and TestClassB to run next. How can i do so. Any ideas.

Note that i am using Springboot here and my test dependency is : spring-boot-starter-test

Comment: "*I want TestClassA to run first and TestClassB to run next.*" - Having a strict oder in test execution is generally regarded as an antipattern. May I ask why you need the strict order?ß

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Comment: @Turing85, I have sequence of steps in a program. where step 1 process some input files and keeps those files in some folder. Now output from step 1 becomes the input to step 2 which is take the file which processed from step 1 and do some other processing.  So this is the scenario. i need to write test case and i am doing so but my like TestCassStep1 , TestClassStep2 but the problem is my TestClassStep2 unit test is running first and this will be failed since Step2 takes input from Step1. So my requirement is my TestClassStep1 should execute first and then TestClassStep2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do using junit 5

```
@Test
@Order(1)    
public void firstTest() {
    output.append("a");
}

@Test
@Order(2)    
public void secondTest() {
    output.append("b");
}
```

check refence here https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-test-order

and for different classes use test suite

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ TestClass1.class, TestClass2.class })
public class AllTests {

}
```

Comment: I have tried with this. But still the classes are running in parallel not in order.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, ordering tests or having tests dependent on each other is an anti pattern and make your testing strategy brittle. So ordering should be handled with care.

With Junit 4 you can order your test

```
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
public class OrderedTest {

@Test
@Order(1)    
public void firstTest() {

}

@Test
@Order(2)    
public void secondTest() {
}

@Test
@Order(3)    
public void thirdTest() {
}
```

}

With Junit 5

```
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public class MethodOrderTest {


@Test
@Order(3)
void test1() {
}

@Test
@Order(1)
void test2() {
}

@Test
@Order(2)
void test3() {
}
```

}